# Shortcut for removing auto-coded items in vs2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Occasionally, while working in visual studio 2012 on a form with visual c#, I'll double click something like a label and it will automatically create a function like

```
private void lblMyLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

If I delete the function then it creates errors and such. Is there an easy way to undo or remove these functions?

Comment: After double-clicking the control and realizing you don't want the code hit Ctrl+Z in the code file.

Comment: Or go into the events window, put your cursor in the event and hit delete.

Comment: What is the event window and where can I find it?

Comment: @user2488335 The events window is a tab of the properties dialog. There will be a button in the properties window to show it. Read the tooltips to find it.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few different ways to deal with this.

- The best is to <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> immediately after you accidentally create the event handler. This will remove it from the code-behind and in the partial class with all the Visual Studio generated code.
- If it is too late for that, try to compile and double click on the error in the window. It will take you to the proper location in the Visual Studio generated code. You can delete it from there manually.
- You can also go to the properties pane for the given form, select the control and go to the events section (click the lightning bolt in the top right corner of the properties pane). Delete the event handler from there and it will delete it in the Visual Studio generated code.